# Android AGDE Visual Studio plug-in breakpoints not working in other threads

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, android-ndk, android-agde

When I try to debug using the AGDE plug-in breakpoints in a different thread are randomly hit. Is there a fix or workaround for this?

I set a breakpoint and it should hit when the code is executed.

AGDE 23.2.87
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 : Version 17.9.2

Steps:

- Create a native app using the AGDE plug-in for Visual Studio 2022.
- Add a portion of code that is in a separate thread.
- Put breakpoints on various parts of the threaded code.
- You should see that SOME of the breakpoints hit but not all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.